# Rails: How to extract plain english date from string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

If I have the string

> string = "Robert Lee Frost (March 26, 1874 – January 29, 1963) was an American
>   poet"

What's the best way to extract the dates from it?

Comment: Do you have the date in same consistent format? (<full month> <two digit day>, <long year>)?

Comment: Yes. Can I somehow get it using strftime("%B %e, %Y") ?

Comment: It's not 2 digit day.. 1-9 is presented as one digit

Comment: strftime gets you fields from a Time object. You have a string which needs to be run through a regexp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if regexp is the best here - but you could try the following:

```
((January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December)\s(\d?\d),\s(\d{4}))
```

This should extract the whole date + the 3 components of your date (Month, Day, Year) and preserve them in the regexp variables. You can experiment with it in [Rubular](http://rubular.com/)

```
str = "Robert Lee Frost (March 26, 1874 – January 29, 1963) was an American poet"
pattern = /((January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December)\s(\d?\d),\s(\d{4}))/

dates = str.scan(pattern).each do |matches|
  Date.parse(matches[0])
end
```

`dates` will hold the born/deceased dates. Be wary of no-matches.

Answer (score 0):

[@tamersalama](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7693/tamersalama) beat me to it.

```
((January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December) [0-9]{2}, [0-9]{4})
```